# WordPress, Nginx | wp-admin returns 405 but I can access website

Tags: wordpress, nginx, http-status-code-405

I have `WordPress` and `Nginx` configuration for the website. This is my `Nginx` conf file

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  website.com;

    root   /var/www/html;
    index  index.php;

    location / {
    if ($request_uri ~ ^/(.*)\.html) {
        return 302 /$1;
        }
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /var/www/html;
    }
    
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Main problem is that website works but I can't login. When I go to `/wp-login.php` I can type in username and password but problem is that on next page it shows `405 Not Allowed` and I have no idea why.

I also saw in console in `Network` tab that it goes to `/wp-admin.php` but then it returns me to `/wp-login.php` with that `405` error.

I already tried to rename `plugins` and `themes` directories to see if those are problem but I they are not.

And this `WordPress` works on my local machine with `Apache`.

I already search `StackOverflow` and `WordPress` forum but I can't find anything on problem where you can see your website but can't login because it returns `405 Error`

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And again. Here I am answering my own question

I fixed the problem by following [this](https://websiteforstudents.com/install-wordpress-4-9-on-ubuntu-17-04-7-10-with-nginx-mariadb-and-php/) guide

Problem was in that `Nginx` configuration